# Ubuntu not recognising only my home WiFi

Tags: networking, wireless, wifi-direct

Like, the Wifi adapter is finding all wifi except my home router.
I tried connecting through the hidden connections.
Restarted the laptop.
Recently I installed NPM, OQASP JUICE SHOP, DVWA, Google Chrome and WPS office.
I Uninstalled all except DVWA. But still my wifi is not displayed.
Please help. I have work from home going on and I need my WiFi :l

Specs : Ubuntu 20.04 
WiFi adapter : Qualcomm QCA9377 and Tp link TL WN823n (I have two coz the internal adapter is malfunctioning)

Comment: Please clarify your use of tags, are you running Ubuntu 20.04 with GNOME?, or Lubuntu 20.04 with LXQt?  Why bug-reporting, as bugs report on launchpad.net (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) and not on a user-support site such as this.  On Lubuntu/LXQt you connect to hidden wifi the same as other wifi, it's not shown until you've entered the details for the wifi & connected.

Comment: Hi @guiverc. There wasn't an ubuntu tag. Anyway it's ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Please follow [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/425180/167115) to make it easier for us to diagnose your issue. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @mchid thank you for your comment. But I resolved the issue. Changed the MAC address of my router and re installed my TP LINK adapter!